# C# How to instantiate new object with Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, constructor, ilogger

I have a class that is using Logger:

```
internal class Class1
{
    private readonly ILogger<Class1> _logger;
    internal Class1(ILogger<Class1> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    internal void Method1()
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

When I try using it, the compiler correctly tells me that there is no constructor that matches this signature:

```
Class1 cl1 = new Class1();
```

I want to use default constructor.  If I understand this correctly, Id need to create default constructor in my `Class1`, and then call another constructor FROM default constructor to make Logger available inside the class.  How do I do that??  Thank you for your help.

Comment: The neat thing about dependency injection and an IOC container is that you _don't_ instantiate anything.

Comment: I don't think you need an empty constructor. I use the same approach as shown here and it works. Perhaps you're missing something elsewhere?

Comment: @maccettura.  When I try to create new instance of Class1 like so `Class1 cl1 = new Class1();` it tells me there isn't a constructor that matches that.

Comment: @isswf Try making your constructor public and see if that resolves the issue. I believe it should fix it.

Comment: @isswf What net version are you using. If net core , can you show your startup file?

Comment: @isswf Correct, that is because you are trying to instantiate `Class1`, you _shouldn't_ be doing that. Whatever class needs the instance of `Class1` should take that in as a dependency in _it's_ constructor. The whole point of Dependency Injection is that you won't be manually instantiating anything

Comment: The caveat to my above comment is there could be instances where you have to instantiate the top level of some service chain, then you should be using the provider locator (`IServiceProvider.GetRequiredService()` in .NET Core/5/6)

Comment: @Serge its net6.0

Comment: @maccettura i'm not sure i follow.  `Class1` is using the `Logger` interface and logger doesn't have to be instantiated inside `Class1`.  This is understood.   But `Class1` is just some concrete type that is used somewhere else:  Why doesn't it have to be instantiated?

Comment: You're using DI wrong. DI happens at runtime, not compile time. You don't instantiate the classes yourself with DI and you don't get ctor compiler errors, you get runtime exceptions.

Comment: What Dependency Injection framework or library do you use? Where's the code.

Answer (score 1):

you have to DI  to the program code if you are using net 6 (or startup if you don't use program)

```
.....

builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(Class1));

var app = builder.Build();
....
```

if youi try to use this way

```
Class1 cl1 = new Class1();
```

you will have to have parameterless construtor

```
internal Class1()
{
        _logger = ... tons of code to create a logger instance
}
```

or may be (I don't know where are you creating the instance  of class)

```
var logger= .. tons of code to create a logger instance
var cl1 = new Class1(logger);
```

Answer (score 0):

You state, *"I want to use default constructor. ... Id need to create default constructor in my Class1, and then call another constructor FROM default constructor to make Logger available inside the class. How do I do that?"*

To do what you are asking,

```
internal class Class1
{
    private readonly ILogger<Class1> _logger;

    // This constructor will pass to the constructor with the matching 
    // signature and it will pass a new instance of the Logger<Class1> class.
    // But in using this approach you will be bypassing the DI, which may be
    // what you need in some cases, but you should still be aware of what is happening
    internal Class1() : this(new Logger<Class1>())
    {
    }

    internal Class1(ILogger<Class1> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }    

    internal void Method1()
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```